# Boole's bane: propositions with the same truth value are equally plausible

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

The following appears on p. 10 of Jaynes' *Probability Theory: The Logic of Science*:

> Evidently, then, it must be the most primitive axiom of plausible reasoning that two
> propositions with the same truth value are equally plausible. This might appear almost too
> trivial to mention, were it not for the fact that Boole himself (Boole, 1854, p. 286) fell into
> error on this point, by mistakenly identifying two propositions which were in fact different –
> and then failing to see any contradiction in their different plausibilities.

What is the particular example Jaynes is referring to?

Comment: I think that the reference is to G.Boole [An Investigation of the Laws of Thought (1854)](https://ia902706.us.archive.org/0/items/investigationofl00boolrich/investigationofl00boolrich.pdf), page 286.